# timed MessageBox in console application

Tags: winapi

I use `MessageBox` function in Win32 console application.
Application does not not use MFC, not even event loop.
I need to make a wrapper, MessageBoxTimed(), that exits
(and dialog box disappears) after N seconds, if user did not press any button.

Is there more or less simple way to do this ?

Comment: See [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/181934) in MSDN for an example of one implementation. We use this in some of our projects and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

This will not be trivial.  Since the `MessageBox()` function itself is modal, you will likely need to start another thread that waits for the predefined number of seconds, and is interrupt-able if the message box is dismissed manually.

If the timer expires, use the `FindWindow()` API to find the handle of the message box and then simulate a click of the OK button, or perhaps more appropriately a keypress of the ESC button.

EDIT:  Actually, not too bad.  This isn't fully tested, may need some additional cleanup, but is enough to get you started.

```
  #include <Windows.h>

  class TimedMB
  {
  public:
     TimedMB() : timeout_(0), caption_(0)
     {
        interrupt_ = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);
     }

     ~TimedMB()
     {
        CloseHandle(interrupt_);
     }

     static DWORD WINAPI timer(LPVOID param)
     {
        TimedMB* mb = reinterpret_cast<TimedMB*>(param);

        if(WAIT_TIMEOUT == WaitForSingleObject(mb->interrupt_, mb->timeout_))
        {
           HWND message_box = FindWindow(NULL, mb->caption_);

           if(::IsWindow(message_box))
           {
              PostMessage(message_box, WM_COMMAND, IDCANCEL, 0);
           }
        }

        return 0;
     }

     void DisplayMessageBox(const char* msg, const char* caption, DWORD timeout)
     {
        timeout_ = timeout;
        caption_ = caption;

        CreateThread(NULL, 0, &TimedMB::timer, this, 0, NULL);
        ::MessageBox(NULL, msg, caption, MB_OKCANCEL);
        ::SetEvent(interrupt_);
     }

  private:
     HANDLE      interrupt_;
     DWORD       timeout_;
     const char* caption_;
  };

  int main()
  {
     TimedMB mb;
     mb.DisplayMessageBox("Hello There!", "My Message Box", 5000);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to dismiss it automatically, I'd avoid using `MessageBox` at all. Instead, I'd just put together a dialog that closes itself after the specified period of time. If memory serves, you can do this pretty easily by setting a time when you display the pseudo-message box dialog. When the time goes off or the user clicks "ok" (or "close", etc.) you close the window and cancel the timer.

Comment: @Andrei: Probably. It'll normally be one call each to SetTimer, KillTimer, and whatever you do to close the dialog. I'd agree with David Heffernan, however, that this doesn't sound like the ideal application for a modal dialog. I'd consider something like a message log window instead.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this. Modal dialogs should be closed by user intervention. Deviating from this pattern is just confusing and non-standard. If you want a message windows that closes itself, then use a balloon window.